# How to display matplotlib graph extract from excel file in tkinter windows python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to use my data from excel to draw a graph and display it on Tkinter windows.
but I couldn't and I don't know how I can do it I search in many places I got only examples to show data from the code. here is my code:

> here the file of Excel [download here](http://webprogramozas.inf.elte.hu/students/nwyuk6/excelfiles/COVID-19.xlsm)

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

df= pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\evil4ever\Desktop\acheraf\project\projetCorona.xlsx') 
tab1=df[0:31]

#Dates=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
Dates = []
for i in range(1,32):
    Dates.append(str(i))


Values=tab1['Cas confirmés']#rmorocco
Values2=tab1['RABAT.SALE.KENITRA']#rabat

f=plt.Figure(figsize=(9,5), dpi=100)

plt.xlabel('days of March')
plt.ylabel('Confirmed cases')
plt.title('Confirmed Cases in March RABAT.SALE.KENITRA ')
plt.bar(Dates,Values,label='all morocco',color='r')
plt.bar(Dates,Values2,label='RABAT.SALE.KENITRA',color='c')
a=f.add_subplot(111)
root= tk.Tk()
canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

> explain the problem:
>   when i run the program is showing this windows look this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YheGR.png)

and the graph is showing here in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixfop.png)
after the code showing the graph which I wanna display on windows not there

> after this line:a=f.add_subplot(111)
>   i add a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5]) is showing something in windows

i search to much for 3 days without any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Figure` instead of `pyplot` when combining `matplotlib` with `tkinter`. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) for an official sample.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":list("ABCD"),"Value":[1,2,3,4,]})
#df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\evil4ever\Desktop\acheraf\project\projetCorona.xlsx') 

f = Figure(figsize=(9,5), dpi=100)

ax = f.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xlabel('days of March')
ax.set_ylabel('Confirmed cases')
ax.set_title('Confirmed Cases in March RABAT.SALE.KENITRA')

df.plot(kind="bar",ax=ax)

root= tk.Tk()
canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but actually i need to show this plots
(plt.bar(Dates,Values,label='all morocco',color='r')
plt.bar(Dates,Values2,label='RABAT.SALE.KENITRA',color='c'))
and data coming from excel is very important to me it will be stupid if i write all that data in python code

Comment: That make no difference. Just plot whatever you need to.

Comment: i tied ax.plt.bar(Dates,Values,label='all morocco',color='r')
and  ax.set_bar(Dates,Values,label='all morocco',color='r')
 but doesn't work can I get your contact FB or Whatsapp or Instagram or mail please

Comment: the problem is my data i don't know how to graph it as i did it look second image you see where the graph is showing not in windows this is the point

Comment: Not sure why you use `pandas` but not utilizing its plotting function, but you can do `ax.bar(Dates,Values)` instead.

Comment: thank you so much and can i ask small question about the colors how to change it for the graph in my case i mean using ax.bar(Dates,Values)

Comment: `ax.bar(..., color=your_list_of_colors)`. All the parameters can be read up on the [documentations here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html).